# How to clone git repo into Eclipse using dumb HTTP protocol

Tags: git, eclipse, http, gitolite

We maintain gitolite3 server. It does not allow anonymous access and thus we added hook to export public folders to the web server. As a result, public data are accessible using "dumb" http protocol. This works in many usecases but the problem is with Eclipse. As found on internet, the integrated git client throws NullPointerException when git server uses "dumb" HTTP (i.e. the server doesn't support Smart HTTP).

We have this in the error log on Win10, Eclipse is version 2020-06 (4.16.0):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.WalkFetchConnection.<init>(WalkFetchConnection.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.newDumbConnection(TransportHttp.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.getConnection(TransportHttp.java:349)
    ...
```

My question is if it is really not possible to use "dumb" git server from Eclipse on Win10? Indeed, the workarround is to clone repo via separate git client and then import it into Eclipse as local git, but this is simply not elegant, enough.

Comment: Eclipse bug report [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=549536)